# VxD: Determine the size of file segments for code and data and their location

Tags: header, exe, loader

I have a sample VxD code here that just shows a message box whenever a DOS prompt is opened or closed under Windows 98.

What I need to know is which fields determine the code segment or page, the data segment, and their size in bytes or pages.
It is actually an old Linear Executable EXE that for VxDs is supposedly always has a signature of "LE".

So far I know that:

`MemPagesCtr` tells how many blocks there are of `MemPageSZ` bytes, that I can make 512 bytes in size and still be sane until now.

`LastPageBytes` says how many bytes the very last portion of the VxD file has, which can be less or probably equal than `MemPageSZ`.

**Which header fields indicate which of the pages is the code, data, or are they always in the same sequence for VxD LE EXE? And how to know where the actual code entry and data start?**

```
;http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/api-simple-completa/api.7z?viasf=1

%include "../../../PC/BIOS/WinAPI/EXE/PE/snippets/DOS_Stubs/NASM/DOS_Stub_classic0xB0.asm"

PE_header:
LE_header:
LE_header_start:

  LE_header_0x00_Signature            db 'LE'
  LE_header_0x02_ByteOrder            db 0 ;0 Little or Big Endian
  LE_header_0x03_WordOrder            db 0 ;0 Little or Big Endian
  LE_header_0x04_FormatLevel          dd 0
  LE_header_0x08_CPUType              dw 2 ;1 286+, 2 386+, 3 486+, 4 586+, 20h i860 N10+, 21h N11+, 40h MIPS Mark I+ (R2000, R3000), 41h MIPS Mark II+ (R6000), 42h MIPS Mark III+ (R4000)
  LE_header_0x0A_TargetOS             dw 4 ;1 OS/2, 2 Win16, 3 DOS 4x, 4 Win386
  LE_header_0x0C_ModuleVersion        dd 0
  LE_header_0x10_Flags                dd 101000000000000000b ;
  LE_header_0x14_MemPagesCtr          dd 3 
  LE_header_0x18_InitialCS            dd 0
  LE_header_0x1C_InitialEIP           dd 0  ;Explicar cómo encuentra y carga las secciones y direcciones de código y datos el VxD
  LE_header_0x20_InitialSS            dd 0
  LE_header_0x24_InitialESP           dd 0
  LE_header_0x28_MemPageSZ            dd 512   ;Tamaño de datos
  LE_header_0x2C_LastPageBytes        dd 0x31
  LE_header_0x30_FixUpSectionSZ       dd 0x85
  LE_header_0x34_FixUpSectionCheck    dd 0
  LE_header_0x38_LdrSectionSZ         dd 0x69
  LE_header_0x3C_LdrSectionCheck      dd 0
  LE_header_0x40_ObjectTableOffset    dd 0xC4  ;from where?
  LE_header_0x44_ObjectTableEntries   dd 3
  LE_header_0x48_ObjectPageMapOffset  dd 0x10C
  LE_header_0x4C_ObjectIterDataMapOff dd 0  ;always 0 for VxD?
  LE_header_0x50_RsrcTableOffset      dd 0
  LE_header_0x54_RsrcTableEntries     dd 0
  LE_header_0x58_ResidentTableOffset  dd 0x118
  LE_header_0x5C_EntryTableOffset     dd 0x123
  LE_header_0x60_ModulDirectivesTable dd 0  ;always 0 for VxD?
  LE_header_0x64_ModulDirectivesEnts  dd 0
  LE_header_0x68_FixupPageTblOffset   dd 0x12D
  LE_header_0x6C_FixupRecordTable     dd 0x13D
  LE_header_0x70_ImportModulesTable   dd 0x1B2
  LE_header_0x74_ImportModulesCount   dd 0
  LE_header_0x78_ImportProcTable      dd 0x1B2
  LE_header_0x7C_PerPageChecksums     dd 0
  LE_header_0x80_DataPagesOffset      dd 0x400   ;0x1000; 0x400;0x2E0;0x1000  ;inicio de código y datos después de la cabecera
  LE_header_0x84_PreloadPageCount     dd 1
  LE_header_0x88_NonResidentNames     dd 0x1434
  LE_header_0x8c_NonResidentNamesLen8 dd 15  ;in bytes
  LE_header_0x90_NonResidentNamesChk  dd 0
  LE_header_0x94_AutomaticDataObject  dd 0
  LE_header_0x98_DebugInformationOff  dd 0
  LE_header_0x9C_DebugInformationLen  dd 0
  LE_header_0xA0_PreloadInstPagesNum  dd 0
  LE_header_0xA4_DemandInstancePgsNum dd 0
  LE_header_0xA8_ExtraHeapAllocation  dd 0
  LE_header_0xAC                      dd 0

;File Offset 0x160, LE header offset 0xB0


;INIT: 
;INIT: 
;INIT: 
;INIT: 



times 16 db 0

dd 0x4000000
dd 0xE8
dd 0
dd 0x2045

dd 1
dd 1
db "LCOD'",0,0,0

dd 0
dd 0x2005
dd 2
dd 1
db "PCOD1",0,0,0
dd 0
dd 0x2023

dd 3
dd 1
db "PDAT"
dd 0x10000

db 0,0,2,0
db 0,0,3,0
db 7
db "MESSAGE"

db 0,0,0,1,3,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
db 0,0x60,0,0,0,0x75,0,0,0,0x75,0,0,0,7,0,0xE1
db 0,2,0x20,0,0x27,0,0x1F,1,0x5F,0,0x65,0,0x69,0,0x6D,0
db 0x71,0,0x75,0,0x79,0,0x7D,0,0x81,0,0x85,0,0x89,0,0x8D,0
db 0x91,0,0x95,0,0x99,0,0x9D,0,0xA1,0,0xA5,0,0xA9,0,0xAD,0
db 0xB1,0,0xB5,0,0xB9,0,0xBD,0,0xC1,0,0xC5,0,0xC9,0,0xCD,0
db 0xD1,0,0xD5,0,0xD9,0,0xDD,0,7,0,0x61,0,2,0,0,7
db 0,0x5B,0,1,0x61,0,7,0,0x18,0,1,0x50,0,7,0,0x21
db 0,3,0x1F,0,7,0,0x11,0,3,0,0,7,0,1,0,3
db 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
db 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,32,32,32

db "MESSAGE_DDB",0,32,0X40,0X31,0
db 32,32,32,"CLASS",0,"'RCODE",0
db 0,0,32,32,32,"PRELOAD DISCARDABLE",0,0
db "CONFORMING",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0


;times 0xD20 db 0


;align 0x1000
align 0x400



;END:  
;END:  
;END:  
;END:  


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;0x1000 en el archivo tiene .00000000
;de base en HIEW, por qué?
;;


;INIT: Page 0
;INIT: Page 0
;INIT: Page 0
;INIT: Page 0

db 0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,1,0,0,0,"MESSAGE"
db 32,0,0,0,0x80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
times 16 db 0
dd 0,0,0
db "verPP",0,0,0
db "1vsR2vsR3vsR",0x83,0xE8,7,0x83,0xF8,0x21,0x73,7,-1,0x24,0x85,0,0,0,0,0xF8
db 0xC3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

times 16*7 db 0

db 0,0,0,0,0,0xCC,0xCC,0xCC,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

;times 16*17 db 0

%define round(n, r) (((n+(r-1))/r)*r)
align 512


;END:  Page 0
;END:  Page 0
;END:  Page 0
;END:  Page 0



;align 512
;_s:
;times (512-_s) db 0

;dd round(_s,512)
;times (512-$$) db 0




;INIT: Page 1
;INIT: Page 1
;INIT: Page 1
;INIT: Page 1


bits 32

mov ecx,0   ;xor ecx,ecx
;xor ecx,ecx
db 0xCD,0x20,3,0,1,0 ;VMMcall Get_Sys_VM_Handle
mov eax,0x30
mov edi,0
xor esi,esi
xor edx,edx
;db 0xCD,0x20,4,0,17,0  ;VxDcall VMCPD.Set_CR0_State  ;17 en vez de 0x17, probar valores WORD o DWORD
db 0xCD,0x20,4,0,0x17,0  ;VxDcall SHELL.Message

ret
mov ecx,0
db 0xEB,0xDE  ;jmps .5


;times 9 db 0


;times 16*29 db 0

align 512



;END:  Page 1
;END:  Page 1
;END:  Page 1
;END:  Page 1





;INIT: Page 2
;INIT: Page 2
;INIT: Page 2
;INIT: Page 2


db "VxD MessageBox",0
db "A VM is created",0
db "A VM is destroyed",0
;db "SEC",0x0B
;db "MESSAGE_DDB",0,0,0



;END:  Page 2
;END:  Page 2
;END:  Page 2
;END:  Page 2
```

Comment: You need to read the object table (`LE_header_0x40_ObjectTableOffset`). The offset in the LE header is relative to the LE magic number. Object table entries will refer to entries in the page map (`LE_header_0x48_ObjectPageMapOffset`, also relative); page data itself is held at the *absolute* offset kept in `LE_header_0x80_DataPagesOffset`. See <http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/pc/os2/OS2_OMF_and_LX_Object_Formats_Revision_8_199406.pdf> (the only difference between LE and LX is the interpretation of the `LE_header_0x2C_LastPageBytes` field)

Comment: Apparently object's table entries are 24-byte long.
What I do is read DWORD at LE_header_0x40_ObjectTableOffset,
add LE header start to it (in this case dword[0x40]=0xC4).
I go to 0xC4 from the LE header start and I have exactly
LE_header_0x44_ObjectTableEntries there (3 in this case).
The last 4 bytes of the 24-byte entry are apparently a name,
but I don't know if it's used or not for locating special sections.

I will add more detais as I find them about this topic questions.

Comment: For these entries, DWORD at 0 is the size of the block when loaded. DWORD at 4 is some relocation I don't know, can be 0. DWORD at 8 are the flags of the block (for executable code, 16/32-bit code, etc.). DWORD at 12 is a page table index starting from 1, typically in order so that we know each block. DWORD at 16 is apparently the number of file "pages" that this block has. DWORD at 20 is a 4-byte name, but it's supposedly reserved and set to 0, but in practice it can have a value, I tested with Windows 98 and the VxD can still be loaded and works if I zero out those object table entry names.